weighted random forest and using caret postResample with test dataset
I have a situation where the sample distribution does not match the population distribution, but I have weights that can be applied to address that issue. I am using ranger with the caseweights=myweights argument to create a random forest model. But I would like to compare a couple of model variations and to that end I have partitioned the original dataset  into train and test datasets using Max Kuhn's caret package.  Thus, both the train and the test datasets have the same mismatch between the sample distribution and the population distribution.
postResample (also from the caret) is a nice convenient function for calculating the RMSE and MAE for the test set. My question is shouldn't the observations in the test dataset also be weighted to calculate these metrics? Does this modification to the code in the postResample function make sense for this situation?
postResample.weighted <- function (pred, obs,weights=NULL)
{ 
...
# original code
      #mse <- mean((pred - obs)^2)
      #mae <- mean(abs(pred - obs))
     
 # --- modified code start here
      if(is.null(weights)) obs.weights <- rep(1,length(obs))
      else obs.weights <- weights
     
      mse <- mean(obs.weights*(pred - obs)^2)
      mae <- mean(obs.weights*abs(pred - obs))
 # ---​ and ends here  
...
}

The code above works, I would just appreciate input on whether or not this approach makes sense.
